# PYQT6 QGraphicsView and event filter not firing

Tags: python, events, filter, qgraphicsview, pyqt6

could someone please tell me what's wrong with the following code I would like to pass mouse clicks through the event filter on a QGraphicsView item. I read the event filter should be installed to the viewport, so in the case of this code that would be the self._scene variable. However, in my example the event filter is ignored and the mousePressEvent event is fired each time without being intercepted.

Any help most welcome and thanks for reading.

```
from PyQt6 import QtWidgets
from PyQt6.QtCore import QEvent, Qt
class display(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(display, self).__init__(parent)
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self._scene)
        self._scene.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, QObject, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress:
            if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.RightButton:
                print("Right button intercepted")
            if event.button() == Qt.MouseButton.LeftButton:
                print("left button intercepted")
        return True

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print("I clicked the mouse  ")
        super(display, self).mousePressEvent(event)


class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.viewer = display(self) # Call class
        VBlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        VBlayout.addWidget(self.viewer)
        self.setLayout(VBlayout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 300, 800, 600)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was QEvent.Type.GraphicsSceneMousePress and not QEvent.Type.MouseButtonPress: hope it helps someone else